# instr not working for closed workbook recordset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation where I need to search for a substring across many workbooks. I have no way of knowing which column the string may be in, nor do the workbooks all have the same column headings, so a SQL statement is out of the question, afaik. I'm trying to do an instr, but it's not finding data I know is there. What am I doing wrong?

[broken instr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57al9.png)

Comment: the code is included in the image link, as well as the locals window showing the results.

Comment: Nice work @Alice. You may want to consider storing an Arrays of you variables in your Dictionary, instead of a single value.  In this example I added a rowcount that would be incremented while you traverse the recordset: `TargetDict.Add SourceName, Array(Cells(RowCount, lcount + 1).Address, Data_to_Duct, Data_to_Did, SourceName, SourceSheet, SourceRange, search_string)`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't actually need all of that information, but you did just give me the idea to store the actual record array so I can print all of the relevant info instead of going to the file. Awesome! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the first parameter for Instr if you are going to specify `vbTextCompare`:

```
strCompare = Instr(1, find_in, search_string, vbTextCompare)
```

I suspect you've shoved an `On Error Resume Next` in there and not turned error trapping back on.

Comment: You are correct about the resume next. And adding the start parameter worked like a charm. THANK YOU!